# What part of speech is the French "à la mode"?

Tags: parts-of-speech, french

What is "à la mode" in French? I am thinking it must be an adjective but wondering how this might be represented in an *arbre syntagmatique*.

I am new to linguistics and just trying to get a solid grasp on this.

Comment: I would say it is simply a preposition with an object, just like *en vogue* and *after a fashion*?

Comment: Well it's a phrase, a prepositional phrase, and I would say it can act as a unit perhaps as an adverb, perhaps as an adjective. My French is far too basic. Also I assume "arbre syntagmatique" is the French term for "syntax tree"?

Comment: Both the English and French Wiktionaries have entries for this phrase. The English one calls it an adjective in both languages, [the French one](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_la_mode) calls it an "Locution adjectivale". Now of course as it's a phrase you can also break it down into its parts but as you're talking about syntax trees I'm assuming each node or branch will bear some label as in x-bar theory such as AP or PP.

Comment: FWIW, the classification as *locution adjectivale* seems to me to be obviously true from a traditional point of view.

Comment: Yes, I assume that's "adjectiv(al) phrase" in English. That would answer the original (vague) question "what is it?" But technically not my new wording as phrases are not parts of speech. Hopefully I didn't mess up the quesiton by rewording it since I think this is pretty much what the OP was asking ...

Answer (score 1):

It is very tempting to analyse it as a *[set phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase)*, and indeed it is leaning toward being one.

However, it is still possible to break it down, and, for instance, put an adjective before "mode" to qualify it : "à la nouvelle mode", meaning more or less "newly fashionable". Or after it : "à la mode française", meaning "in the french fashion".

Compare this to French set phrase "pour le moment". It is **not** possible to add an adjective qualifying "moment", either before or after it.

Therefore, I think it is still better to analyse "à la mode" as a full-fledged prepositional phrase.

Comment: It certainly is, but in American English at least, it's a fixed phrase, meaning 'with ice cream'. Generally spelled without diacritic.

Comment: The OP is asking « What is "à la mode" _in French_ », so I gave an answer about its analysis in french grammar. 
I never heard about that use of the phrase in american english, and I find it surprising.

Comment: Entirely correct; I wasn't commenting on the French facts. But the phrase is fixed in American English, where it comes from _pie ala mode_ 'pie with ice cream'. Ask for it in the US wherever pies are on the menu; they may not serve it, but they know what it means.

Comment: English Wiktionary gives it two senses in English. The American ice cream one which I'd never heard of but also the sense of fashionable, trendy. In English it's obviously affected and it's a set phrase used as an adjective that can be modified with words such as "very".

Comment: @Typhon: This answer just makes me want to ask some questions about "setness" of set phrases! "Set phrase" as a concept seems to have a lot of trouble setting in. The Wikipedia article was missing and has been in convulsions since I created it as a stub a few years ago: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase

Comment: Before I ask how fixed set phrases are I'm asking if it's a linguistic concept at all: [Does linguistics have a concept of “set phrase” with a meaning differing from “idiom”?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4596)

Comment: It's very confusing because in french if something follows the verb sembler or etre it is considered an adjective.  This is also the case in comparisons.  It was just a question to ponder and I think I have pondered too much.  Curious what anyone thought or if it could be anything other than an adjective in french.  Thanks for the responses.

Comment: The verbs sembler and être can be followed by any number of things that are not adjectives and are never considered as such.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it is an [adjective](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%C3%A0%20la%20mode) in *both* English and French. It's [synonymous](http://thesaurus.com/browse/a+la+mode) with en vogue, haute, trendy, etc.In English, it has additional applications in food, such as [topped with ice cream](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/a+la+mode) or braised or stewed in vegetables. It literally translates as [in the style or fashion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_la_mode).

Comment: The OP was specifically asking what it is in French. The English stuff is interesting enough to mention in a comment - I think somebody already did. But it's not an answer.

Comment: I understand that. That's why I included the French translation. It is French for *fashionable* or *stylish* and is synonymous with *en vogue* and *haute* in French. It's an adjective in both languages.

Comment: But Typhon has given evidence for why it is not (yet) a set phrase, but a PP, and so does not have a "part of speech".