# The Correct Research Methodology To Substantiate If an Expression is an Idiom?

Tags: semantics, parts-of-speech, lexical-semantics, idiomaticity, philology

<sup>***Related:***

- [Does linguistics have a concept of "set phrase" with a meaning differing from "idiom"?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4596/does-linguistics-have-a-concept-of-set-phrase-with-a-meaning-differing-from-i/4597#4597)

- [In the Gospels, Can “Day of:” the Passover - be Interpreted Idiomatically?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/22039/in-the-gospels-can-day-of-the-passover-be-interpreted-idiomatically)</sup>

---

## 1. Question, Reference Request: Research Methodology

***What is the proper methodology to validate - or refute - whether an expression is an Idiom?***

What are the Evidences and Criteria that would substantiate those conclusions?

***Note:*** The question here **is not to identify if a specific phrase is idiomatic** - **but rather:** to identify the correct methodologies to use.

Are there any recommended / ***published guidelines*** or ***example studies***?

---

## 2. Context, Validating or Refuting Chrysostom's Idiom Claim

[Chrysostom, (349-407 CE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Chrysostom) claimed that an expression was idiomatic - but in order to validate or refute his claim - a valid and systematic methodology would have to be used:

> **[Homilies on Matthew (Chrysostom) > Homily 81:](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/200181.htm)** - "Then came the day of unleavened bread, when the passover must be killed; ***by the word came, meaning this, it was near, it was at the doors*** ...

---

## 3. Current Working Methodology

1. **Exhaustive Samples:** Examples from contemporaneous texts, (Example searching Greek Literature: ***lemma:ἔρχομαι OR lemma:γίνομαι AND lemma:ἡμέρα***);
2. **Literal Uses** - Where the plain meaning can be inferred, ***in those contexts***, (or not).
3. **Figurative Uses:** If the implied meaning is certainly not its literal meaning;
4. **Contradictions Imposed:** In cases of ambiguity - where a contradiction would be imposed onto the text whether either the literal or figurative meaning are assumed;
5. **Contemporaneous Identification:** Whether contemporaneous authorities also identified the expression as idiomatic or not.
6. etc ... ?

***What is missing here? What is the "actual criteria" normally expected in order to validate or refute such a claim?***

Comment: What do you mean by "idiomatic expression" -- for example "keep tabs on", "kick the bucket"? By "actually used", do you mean "can be shown to have been used at least once", or do you want a higher token count?

Comment: @user6726 - **A.)** Yes, that is what I mean by idiomatic expression; **B.)** However, my question is about "when hypothesizing ***IF*** an unknown expression is actually an idiom" **C.)** So, in this case - I don't already know if the expression is an idiom, but I think so.  So, ***what would be the standard criteria for proving it?***; **D.)** I will clarify the question a bit more with your comment;

Comment: Give us more details: the actual expression, language etc.

Comment: @AlexB. **A.)** The phrase I am currently researching is actually in Greek, and "Came the Day", (lemma:ἔρχομαι OR lemma:γίνομαι AND lemma:ἡμέρα); **B.)** But the question is intended to be about methodology and language neutral - not necessarily to ask about any particular idiom, (thought it would be helpful); **C.)** I will update the question to clarify that it is about general methodology, for any given phrase - in any given language;

Comment: @elikakohen Have you seen this already? http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/4597/445

Comment: @AlexB. - Thank you.  **A.)** From what I can understand, it appears the question is asking what the terminology is for "fixed expression idioms" and "dynamically expressed idioms"; **B.)** That seems to be a very different question from "Systematic Methodology"; **C.)** I will follow their references to see where they lead; - Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

In another answer, [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17271/how-can-psg-describe-the-vertical-dimension-of-sentence-structure/17351#17351), I introduced the notion of a derived phrase structure rule, as an alternative to phrase structure derivation.  In effect, every constituent, together with its grammatical category, becomes a phrase structure rule, and any finite subset of these which is a basis for the language can be considered a lexicon for the grammar.  This handles the case of idioms which are constituents, without any apparatus other than the parsing and look up needed for the language anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I consider an expression an idiom when I find I wouldn't express the idea in this way in English or in my mother tongue. But if you want a scientic method to ascertain whether an expression is an idiom or not you will get into a quagmire.

Comment: - rogermue - **A.)** Just applying any / some methodology - would lend some amount of credibility; **B.)** Hopefully, at least enough to merit a reasonable review.