# How are to-infinitive clauses treated in x-bar syntax trees?

Tags: syntax-trees, phrase-structure, x-bar-theory, infinitive

For example:

The man refused to send any letters to that place.

This is what I have so far from the [Syntax Tree Generator.](http://mshang.ca/syntree/?i=%5BS%20%5BNP%20%5Bdet%5BThe%5D%5D%5BN%27%5BN%5Bman%5D%5D%5D%5D%20%5BVP%20%5BV%27%5BV%5Brefused%5D%5D%20%5BX%5Binf%5Bto%5D%5D%5BV%5Bsend%5D%5D%5BNP%5Bdet%5Bany%5D%5D%5BN%27%5BN%5Bletters%5D%5D%5BPP%5BP%27%5BP%5Bto%5D%5D%5D%5BNP%5Bdet%5Bthat%5D%5D%5BN%27%5BN%5Bplace%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%20)

What should replace the X there?

Comment: "Refuse" is a catenative verb, so I'd label it a VP functioning as catenative complement of "refuse"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a fan of X-bar syntax, so I'll just offer a couple of remarks which might be relevant.

Your tree does not show that "send any letters to that place" is a constituent, but clearly it is.  (1) It can undergo the rule of VP (or V') deletion: "Henry told the man to send them, but he refused to (0=send them)."  (2) it can be coordinated with a like constituent: "The man refused to send them or destroy them." (3) It can be replaced by "do so" (see Lakoff and Ross "Criterion for VP constituency").

The X constituent is a complement of "refuse", but it doesn't seem to be nominal -- at least "He refused it" with "it" referring back to "to send them" sounds pretty bad to me, so that makes X some sort of S or verbal constituent.  I think McCawley would make it a V'.

In my own theory [How can PSG describe the vertical dimension of sentence structure?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17271/how-can-psg-describe-the-vertical-dimension-of-sentence-structure), which has no bars but distinguishes 4 degrees of obliqueness of phrases, it's an S2, meaning that it cannot contain any constituent of obliqueness less than 2 (which precludes Tense, Subject, sentence -ly adverb like "possibly", performative adverb, vocative, appositive). The grammatical relation "2" is like the same relation of Relational Grammar, and is the phrasal correspondent to a traditional accusative.